# how to make bootstrap 4 cards according to mongodb json response?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, flask, jinja2, flask-pymongo

so i have this document.(**see image below**). now i want to show this response in the form of bootstrap 4 cards. in this document i have 6 information's. so i have to make cards for each and every information. which i dont want to do. instead of that i want these process to be dynamic. Like if i have more than 6 documents i want bootstrap cards to be genarated automatically.i am using flask.

[image]

*Please let me know if you want further info*. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

finally i solved the problem. actually i used bootstrap shadow property to make card like component.